# Create uniformly distributed sample PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create uniformly distributed samle from my data. I want the final sample to be uniformly distributed among years. The data looks like

| data | value |
| --- | --- |
| 15-01-2006 | id_1 |
| 14-02-2015 | id_2 |
| 14-05-2021 | id_3 |
| 13-09-2020 | id_1 |

I want to see the object only once. That is, if id_*  has already hit the previous year, we will not take it next year.

but I can't figure out how to use `dbms_random.value` so that the final data is uniformly distributed over each year.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow exactly what you want.  Do you want to pick exactly N random rows from the table for each year (i.e. if N=10 then you'd pick exactly 10 rows from 2006, 10 from 2007, etc.)?  What happens if N = 10 but there are only 4 rows from 2006?  Do you want to have a constant probability of picking each row (or a constant probability of picking each row within a particular year) such that the probability distribution is uniform but the end result will have random fluctuations (i.e. you might expect to get 10 rows for each year but sometimes get 9 or 12 because of randomness)?

Comment: Yes, I want to have a constant probability of picking each row such that the probability distribution is uniform but the end result will have random fluctuations, exactly:)

Comment: OK.  Are there an equal (or roughly equal) number of rows for each year?  So you can just get a random sample for the table?  Or do you need to adjust the probability for each year because the source table isn't uniformly distributed?

Comment: Yes, I need to adjust the probability for each year, I edited the task

Comment: Please post the **exact** output you expect. Now you indicated random values, so for determining this output assume you got .26117, .01592, .86402, .59365.  You also indicated *already hit the previous year, we will not take it next year* would the  data (date?) 13-09-2020 not be included. Further, explain what you mean by Previous Year and  Next Year  as only only 2 of your data points (14-05-2021, 13-09-2020) appear to in a previous/next relationship. Do not put this in a comment, but update the question.